# Reloading a module when inheriting from it causes typeError. I wonder why

Tags: python, inheritance, typeerror, reload

So, i've got the following setup which throws me the errors posted in the end of the question. Can somebody tell me why? I'm sure the error would make total sense when somebody explains it, but i just can't figure it out myself.

**baseCmds.py**

```
class base():
    ....
```

**mainCmds.py**

```
import baseCmds
reload(baseCmds)
class main(baseCmds.base):
    def __init__(self):
        baseCmds.base.__init__(self)
    ....
```

**simpleCmds.py**

```
import baseCmds
reload(baseCmds)
class simple(baseCmds.base):
    def __init__(self):
        baseCmds.base.__init__(self)
    ....
```

**build.py**

```
import mainCmds
import simpleCmds

reload(mainCmds)
reload(simpleCmds)

m = mainCmds.main()
s = simpleCmds.simple()
```

Then depending on the order of the `reload()` statements in `build.py` I get either

```
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<string>", line 12, in <module>
#   File "C:\\Users\\Vasko\\Documents\\maya\\scripts\\vsRigging\\builds\\vsTest\\characters\\TestGuy\\body.py", line 62, in <module>
#     build()
#   File "C:\\Users\\Vasko\\Documents\\maya\\scripts\\vsRigging\\builds\\vsTest\\characters\\TestGuy\\body.py", line 59, in build
#     buildRig(assetName="TestGuy", assetType="character", debug=0)
#   File "C:\\Users\\Vasko\\Documents\\maya\\scripts\\vsRigging\\builds\\vsTest\\characters\\TestGuy\\body.py", line 19, in buildRig
#     m = mainCmds.main()
#   File "C:/Users/Vasko/Documents/maya/scripts\vsRigging\rigCmds\bodyCmds\mainCmds.py", line 14, in __init__
#     baseCmds.base.__init__(self)
# TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with base instance as first argument (got main instance instead)
```

or

```
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<string>", line 12, in <module>
#   File "C:\\Users\\Vasko\\Documents\\maya\\scripts\\vsRigging\\builds\\vsTest\\characters\\TestGuy\\body.py", line 62, in <module>
#     build()
#   File "C:\\Users\\Vasko\\Documents\\maya\\scripts\\vsRigging\\builds\\vsTest\\characters\\TestGuy\\body.py", line 59, in build
#     buildRig(assetName="TestGuy", assetType="character", debug=0)
#   File "C:\\Users\\Vasko\\Documents\\maya\\scripts\\vsRigging\\builds\\vsTest\\characters\\TestGuy\\body.py", line 20, in buildRig
#     s = simpleCmds.simple()
#   File "C:/Users/Vasko/Documents/maya/scripts\vsRigging\rigCmds\basicCmds\simpleCmds.py", line 7, in __init__
#     baseCmds.base.__init__(self)
# TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with base instance as first argument (got simple instance instead)
```

Comment: First, reloading is not recommended in Python at all. But I don't understand what you are trying to do: why reload a module immediately after importing it?  Lastly, it would be easier to figure out what is going on if you would include the complete error report, and not just the one-line error message.

Comment: First, if reloading is not recommended, can you please elaborate? To help you understand what i'm trying to do: I reload a module immediately after importing it, because I am writing the code in an external IDE and the interpreter needs to reload the modules, so my changes go true. Lastly, to be easier for you to figure out, I've included the complete error report.

Comment: It makes no sense to reload a module immediately after importing it.  Reloading is to pick up changes that have been made *since* the module was imported.  Just remove all the reloads.

Comment: And BTW, one of the reasons reload is difficult in Python is because it will redefine the classes in those modules, and now you have two different classes with the same name.  Existing objects made from the class will not refer to the new class. It's a mess.

Comment: Right that second comment seems to sort of explain the issue in my situation., so thanks for that. As for the reloads, removing them causes the interpreter to pick up an old version (the one that has been called the first time I've ran the script). Do you have any suggestions as to how to get it to read my latest changes, but not create two different classes?

Comment: There isn't a good way. You should restart the Python process when you change the code.

Comment: Right, that's what I thought as well. Then I found this dirty hack somewhere, just go through the `sys.modules` dictionary and use `del` on the once containing my package name. Not ideal, but does the job for me and considering im running this code in a simple tool that's ran directly by the user I should be fine.